# Beamer: locally change frametitle?

Tags: beamer

Using `\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}`, I redefined the `frametitle` command so that, for each frame, it is automatically generated from section and subsection names (with miniframe-like bullets, also).

Now, I also want to access to "blank frames" locally (e.g. for summary slides). But even frames obtained with `\begin{frame)[plain]` are using that redefined `frametitle`...

Is there an easy way to achieve that? Is there a way to redefine `frametitle` for some frames only?

Comment: Please make a MWE

Comment: Well... I was hoping for a quick and dirty answer, but I may have to resort to a MWE indeed (even though in that case "minimal" does not mean "short"...).

Comment: Even for quick and dirt answers I'd like to test my code before posting. This is much easier if there is some compilable document as a starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing your exact code, you can try redefining `frametitle` locally. The defintion of the empty `frametitle` applies only to the frames inside the curly brackets (`{ }`).

```
\documentclass{beamer}

% general redefintion
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\textbf{\insertframetitle}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Some nice title}
Dummy text.
\end{frame}


% Blank frame
{\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{}

\begin{frame}{I will not appear}
This slide has no title
\end{frame}
} % end of untitled frames

\begin{frame}{Some title again}
Dummy text.
\end{frame} 


\end{document}
```

This results in (... well, it's only some mostly white slides):

[image: slides]

Comment: You don't need `\usetheme{default}`, as the name says, this theme is loaded by default

Comment: Quick and dirty! Nice! (Still, should have thought about this... ^^)